# RSpec Testing JSON API: Problems setting header variables

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I'm trying to create an API following the codeschool course "Surviving APIs with Rails" as a bit of a guide.
Here's my controller index:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: Project.all, status: 200 }
    format.all { head 406 }
  end
end
```

When I try to test the controller with rspec like this (as in the course):

```
 get :index, {}, { 'Accept' => Mime::JSON }
 expect(response.status).to eq(200)
```

The request does not get set as JSON, it's set as html. (and the test fails: expected 200 got 406)
However if I try this:

```
  request.accept = Mime::JSON.to_s
  get :index, {}, {}
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
```

The request accept header is set to "application/json", and the test passes.

So I do have a work around but I thought I could set different headers when using the [get method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get). I even tried what the comments said [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers/get). What am I missing that 'Accept' => Mime::JSON does not work?

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, I got some help from support at codeschool:

> Looks like the get method works differently on controller test/specs than they do on request specs/ integration tests (which is what we used in the course).
>
> I believe your examples are controller specs, which are probably using this one - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_co... From reading the docs, doesn't look like there's a way to pass headers values on that method, so your alternative is probably the only way to set the headers. Integration tests, on the other hand, use this other get method https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_di... which is what we used in the course.

Thank you code school.

Comment: both links are broken.

Comment: ya, it's not much help anymore. And I can't find the email from their support to fix it.